# How to write a conditional Gmail add-on trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like the addon to reload only when a new thread is selected, instead of reloading for every different message.

```
"contextualTriggers": [{
  "unconditional": {
  },
  "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CacheService to track the ID of the current Gmail thread inside the buildAddon method. If the thread Id changes, call the main method else skip.

Comment: In that case, the addon trigger method will return void. This would cause the addon to show an empty screen.